# Parsing urls from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, urllib, urlparse

I am trying to parse urls from a dataframe to get the 'path'. My dataframe has 3 columns: ['url'], ['impressions'], ['clicks']. I want to replace all the urls by their Path. Here is my code:

```
import csv
from urllib.parse import urlparse

    fic_in = 'file.csv'

    df = pd.read_csv(fic_in)
    obj = urlparse(df['url'])
    df['url'] = obj.path
    print(df)
```

The csv file contains thousands of urls and 2 other columns of informations about the urls. For a technical reason, I can't parse the urls manipulating the csv, but I have to parse them in the dataframe.
When I execute this code, I have the following error that I don't really understand:

```
File "/Users/adamn/Desktop/test_lambda.py", line 33, in <module>obj = urlparse(df['url'])
File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/parse.py", line 389, in urlparse
    url, scheme, _coerce_result = _coerce_args(url, scheme)
File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/parse.py", line 125, in _coerce_args
    return _decode_args(args) + (_encode_result,)
File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/parse.py", line 109, in _decode_args
    return tuple(x.decode(encoding, errors) if x else '' for x in args)
File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/parse.py", line 109, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(x.decode(encoding, errors) if x else '' for x in args)
File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1442, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I do get there is an error so what am I doing that is not possible to do? And how can I resolve it or just use another way to get this done?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: have you tried regular expression filter? If that's not working for you!

Comment: Can you provide the whole stack trace around that error message? It might help troubleshoot this, if the existing answer doesn't already solve your problem.

Comment: @NischayNamdev Well no I haven't, I thought it would be easier with urllib because the library was made for it.

Comment: @joanis Yes of course, I will add the full error message in comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

urlparse only takes one string at a time, not a series.

try:

```
df["URL"] =df["URL"].astype(str).apply(lambda x: urlparse(x).path)
```

Comment: I just tried this and I got a new error that I do not really understand either : `File "/Users/adamndubois/Desktop/test_lambda.py", line 33, in <module>
    df['url'] =df['url'].apply(lambda x: urlparse(x).path) AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'decode' `

Comment: @AdamD97 I modied the code to enforce the column "URL" being a string, however if it was not already a string you should check the data in the column is correct

Comment: Yes, the type of my 'url' column was 'object'. It works that way, thank you very much !